# Xposed - hook MTP method running in android.process.media method

Tags: xposed

I wish to hook a MTP method `bool MtpDevice::openSession()` in [MtpDevice.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/mtp/MtpDevice.cpp), this method should be running in `android.process.media`.

When I try to hook package name `android.process.media`, it do not being hit at all.(Maybe this process name is not a package name at all).

Since this process is launched by system bootup, I do not know how can I hook it.

Comment: Are you sure Xposed can be used to C++ functions? I only remember that it can be used to hook Java and Java native methods. For C++ methods I would prefer Frida as it has built-in hooking capabilities for C/C++ methods.

Comment: @Robert You are right, Xposed can not work on C++ function. I read some Frida document as your suggestion, but sounds like it's for application specific native code (within app's lib directory). for my case, the native so is in system framework, not sure if it's possible for Frida to hook it.